# Unfamiliar Form icons in VB6 project

Tags: forms, vb6, icons

I'm a C# programmer and my knowledge about VB is practically zero. Ironically, at my work currently i'm working on a project which is based on a legacy VB6 version. And I find a lot of stuff unfamiliar to me, like the two following Form icons.
            [image] and [image]

This second icon looks kinda blurry, like hidden files or folders in Windows Explorer. Can anyone tell the difference between these two? What do they imply about the Form in question?

Comment: Maybe it's inherited? Can you do that in VB6?

Comment: AFAIK VB6 is NOT Object-oriented.

Comment: Well, it is has week OOP features.
[VB6 Object and data types](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10096040/vb6-object-and-data-types)

Comment: Nope, the Form Code says nothing that seems like it inherits anything. At least not to me.

Comment: VB 6 does support *some* object-oriented features, but it does *not* support inheritance. Even if it did, this wouldn't be reflected in the icons. As Ahmad just answered, this has to do with MDI forms.

Comment: @Nero - depends on what you defined "object oriented" as meaning. As far as I am concerned, it has the no. 1 feature of OO - encapsulation, and no. 2 - polymorphism. What it *doesn't* have is constructors, method overloading, and implementation inheritance.

Comment: @MarkBertenshaw: sorry, as i mentioned my knowledge about vb6 is practically zero. and to me the codes seem to follow procedural programming than OOP. but thanks thanks for the points

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The icon that shows a large visible form and a small blurred form is an MDI Parent form. The icon that shows a large blurred form and a small visible form is an MDI Child form.

You can see the difference in the following side-by-side comparison:

[image]

VB 6 automatically names new MDI Parent forms `MDIFormN`, where *N* is a number. MDI child forms are just regular forms with the `MDIChild` property set to `True`.

The MDI acronym, of course, refers to a [multiple document interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_document_interface). You can read more about MDI applications in Windows [here on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644908.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

The icon with the faint inset form is for an MDI parent form. If you created an MDI child form it would have a similar icon, but less faint.